# Ad-Hoc Install for test users fails on sync

Tags: xcode4, itunes, adhoc

I have created an ad hoc of my app so that I can test it on some other devices.

All seems to go ok and I drag the App.ipa file into itunes and it installs onto iTunes no problems, but then when I go to sync the devices to install the app's I get the 'App Name' failed to install.

So I belive I have done all process correctly etc so any ideas what coul dbe going wrong? Or suggestions

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

AS this is empty and part of an ongoing issue I have had and fixed thought bets to inform people.  Having been in contact with apple and tech support and going back and forth, it turns out that xcode 4.2 can cause issue with cert. and with 4.3 not being a release version I could not use this to output the file but for testing I also tried this , and still had issue, reported as a bug and also apple got back to me and I solved the issue by simply un ticking the refresh option within the organiser, this is a known bug and was ment to have been fixed in 4.3 but could have to wait.